# how to store multiple id in multiple column

Tags: mysql, ajax, spring

first table :

```
   table Name : ssc_course;
   +---------------+-----------------+------------+
   | ssc_course_id | ssc_course_name | qualify_id |
   +---------------+-----------------+------------+
   |             1 | HSC             |          1 |
   |             2 | Diploma         |          1 |
   |             3 | ITI             |          1 |
   +---------------+-----------------+------------+
```

second table :
table name :ssc_stream

```
  +---------------+--------------------+-----------------+
  | ssc_stream_id | ssc_stream_name    | ssc_course_id(fk) |
  +---------------+--------------------+-----------------+
  |             1 | Science            |               1 |
  |             2 | Commers            |               1 |
  |             3 | Arts               |               1 |
  |            17 | Computer Engg      |               2 |
  |            18 | Mechanical Engg    |               2 |
  |            19 | Civil  Engg        |               2 |
  |            20 | Electronics & TELE |               2 |
  |            21 | E&TC               |               2 |
  +---------------+--------------------+-----------------+
```

third table :(master table)
table name : ssc_college

```
     +------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+-
     | ssc_clg_id | clg_login_id | ssc_stream_id | ssc_course_id |
     +------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+-
     |          9 |            2 |             1 |             1 |
     |         10 |            2 |             1 |             1 |
     |         11 |            2 |             2 |             1 |
     |         12 |            2 |             2 |             1 |
     |         13 |            2 |             3 |             1 |
     |         14 |            2 |             3 |             1 |
     |         15 |            3 |             1 |             1 |
     |         16 |            3 |             1 |             1 |
     |         17 |            3 |             2 |             1 |
     |         18 |            3 |             2 |             1 |
     |         19 |            3 |             3 |             1 |
     |         20 |            3 |             3 |             1 |
     |         21 |            4 |             1 |             1 |
     |         22 |            4 |             1 |             1 |
     |         23 |            4 |             2 |             1 |
     |         24 |            4 |             2 |             1 |
     |         25 |            4 |             3 |             1 |
     |         26 |            4 |             3 |             1 |
     |         27 |            5 |            17 |             2 |
     |         28 |            5 |            17 |             2 |
     |         29 |            5 |            18 |             2 |
     |         30 |            5 |            18 |             2 |
     |         31 |            5 |            19 |             2 |
     |         32 |            5 |            19 |             2 |
     |         33 |            5 |            20 |             2 |
     |         34 |            5 |            20 |             2 |
     |         35 |            5 |            21 |             2 |
     |         36 |            5 |            21 |             2 |
     |         38 |            6 |            17 |             2 |
     |         39 |            6 |            17 |             2 |
     |         40 |            6 |            18 |             2 |
     *************************************************************
```

I am trying to save course,stream  id's into ssc_college table. 
           1 course have multiple stream how can i insert this type of values
           ex. course 1-diploma and this course have multiple stream like-
             1.comp. engg , 2.mechanical ,3.e&tc i want to add course id and 
          stream id  at a time of third (ssc_college) table.
          and  multiple stream for multiple course how i can add at a time 
                multiple parent and multiple child id in mysql table.
         Note: stream are dependant of course table.

Comment: Please research on `batch update` functionality.

Comment: Storing multiple anything in a column is not something you would ever want to do. It violates 1NF.